# How can I transform a subquery to join in gorm?

Tags: mysql, database, go, go-gorm

I am using GORM and I have these models:

```golang
type User struct {
  ID    uint
  UUID  uuid.UUID
  Email string
}

type Profile struct {
  ID     uint
  UUID   uuid.UUID
  Domain string
  UserID uuid.UUID
  User   User `gorm:"references:UUID"`
}
```

Now I want to find all users that have a profile with domain e.g. `example.com`.

I already tried some "Join" queries but I did not get it to work. However I managed to get it working by using a subquery:

```
var users []users

DB.Where(
  "uuid IN (?)",
  DB.Select("user_id").Where("domain = ?", "example.com").Table("profiles")
).Find(&users)
```

But I don't think this is a pretty elegant way. I think a join would be more straight forward. How do I convert this subquery to a join query?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you select the wrong column on your subquery `DB.Select("user_id")` should be `DB.Select("uuid")` right? (`gorm: "references:UUID"`)

Comment: @DavidYappeter no the subquery works fine. The field on the profiles table is called `user_id` and it references the field `uuid` of the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
DB.Select("u.*").Table("users u").Joins("INNER JOIN profiles p on p.user_id = u.uuid").Where("p.domain = ?", "example.com").Find(&users)
```

this will result:

```
SELECT u.* FROM users u INNER JOIN profiles p on p.user_id = u.uuid WHERE p.domain = "example.com"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer using gorm bulit-in feature instead of raw query join, you can try this:

```
profile := &Profile{Domain: "example.com"}
user := &User{}

db.Select("User.*").Joins("User").Model(&Profile{}).Where(profile).Find(&user)
```

If we use gorm Debuging mode like this:

```
db.Debug().Select("User.*").Joins("User").Model(&Profile{}).Where(profile).Find(&user)
```

The SQL query log will be like this:

```
SELECT User.*,`User`.`id` AS `User__id`,`User`.`uuid` AS `User__uuid`,`User`.`email` AS `User__email` FROM `profiles` LEFT JOIN `users` `User` ON `profiles`.`user_id` = `User`.`uuid` WHERE `profiles`.`domain` = 'example.com'
```